# How to fix CPU spike?

Tags: performance, tkinter

I have a simple program that indefinitely places 3 adjacent pictures. When no other processes are running, the CPU usage remains around 1%. However, when I open programs that use a lot of my CPU, (such as my internet broswer) it causes my program to hover between 10% and 15% CPU usage. When I close the browser, my program goes back to 1% usage. Is there a quick fix for this? Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x100')

im1=Image.open('c1.jpg')
im2=Image.open('c2.jpg')
im3=Image.open('c3.jpg')
photo1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im1)
photo2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im2)
photo3=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im3)

def start(root, L1):
    L1['im'] =photo1
    L2['im'] =photo2
    L3['im'] =photo3

    root.after(10, start, root, L1)

L1=Label(im='')
L1.place(x=0, y=0)
L2=Label(im='')
L2.place(x=100, y=0)
L3=Label(im='')
L3.place(x=200, y=0)

start(root, L1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you really need to be setting the label to the same image 100 times a second? That is faster than the eye can perceive.

Comment: This code is just a simple example I wrote in order to convey a problem I am having with a larger project

Comment: So, in your actual program, do you really need to be updating the label every 10ms? What if you change it to 30? 100? 500? Do you still get good application performance without the spike?

Comment: Yeah 10 is ideal. It's very odd to me because I can keep the CPU usage under 1% when its running alone...

Comment: Considering you are calling a function 100 times a second, a 10% CPU usage doesn't seem particularly unusual. You're causing the underlying libraries to think it needs to redraw the screen at 100fps.

Comment: Alright that makes sense to me. I just dont understand why it stays at 1% until I open another program